# XSLT perform identity transform and use transformed data

Tags: xml, xslt

Fiddling still with XSLT. Changed my approach to a solution by using id-transformation, but can't get out, how to use the transformed items directly (if possible)

Sources are two lists, that will be combined by the id-transformation. The mapping-list the transformed xml, the items are imported into $items variable.

```
<mapping>
    <sub id="1" item="a" group="a">
    <sub id="2" item="b" group="a">
    <sub id="3" item="d" group="b">
    <sub id="4" item="e" group="b">
    <sub id="5" item="f" group="c">
</mapping>

<items>
    <item id="a" val="OK"/> 
    <item id="b" val="ERROR"/>
    <item id="c" val="OK"/>
    <item id="d" val="OK"/>
    <item id="e" val="OK"/>
    <item id="f" val="OK"/>
</items>
```

Using id-transformation, i change the sub-nodes to NewItem-nodes, adding information from the second list and adding the desired attributes.

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sub">
    <xsl:element name="NewItem">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$items/item[@id = ./@item]/@group"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But after that it seems I can't do anything with the generated NewItem-nodes. Using a template, selecting them by type, nothing works, is it really only possible to generate for output, not for further processing?

Comment: Seems you didn't learn anything from the answers of your almost identical question -- I am too-lazy to copy the same answer here -- and also to copy the same comment, explaining its details. One can spend their time better by reading a good XSLT book in order to get to know the basics of the language.

Answer (score 1):

With xslt version=1.0 you can use a extension "not-set".
Put your new generated content in a variable and use this

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($NewItem_var) />
```

To make it  woke you have to add following lines.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
    version="1.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 1.0, if you create a variable containing nodes it is a result tree fragment and all you can do is do `xsl:copy-of` or `xsl:value-of`. If you want to further process or select nodes in a result tree fragment then you need to use an extension function like `exsl:node-set` first e.g. if you have `<xsl:variable name="items"><NewItems><xsl:apply-templates/></NewItems></xsl:variable>` and you want to apply-templates to nodes in that result tree fragment you need

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($items)/NewItems/NewItem"/>
```

where in your stylesheet you bind `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"`. Note however that for a portable stylesheet you might need to check the documentation of your XSLT processor whether it supports a `node-set` function in the EXSLT namespace or a different one (like MSXML does), in that case you need to check with `function-available` which function is supported and write `xsl:choose` checks to ensure a supported function is used in the `apply-templates`.

And if you can move to an XSLT 2.0 processor you will find that the restriction is gone, you can use any temporary tree in XSLT 2.0 like a primary input tree, without any need to use an extension function.